# Why can't google make it automatic to add all the activities to manifest file when building the project?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm wondering Why can't google make it automatic to add all the activities to manifest file when building the project? Why should we every time manually declare it..?
is there any specific reason for that?

**Edit**:
i'm aware that it is possible , it will automatically add to manifest when we add new Activity through Add Activity by right clicking on the package name.

My question is why google make it automatically detect the activities (that we create it in a usual way) in the program and add to manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Eclipse, it is automatical. New->Android->Activity. This adds all the manifest declarations. However I don't know about the Andriod Studio case.

Comment: Same in Android Studio